# Patterns or techniques for generalizing objects

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that requires being able to create, save, and play animated graphics on live streams. So far, I've been able to define whatever graphic types I want to let the user build and display on screen, but these are specific to the kinds of graphics we need to display at work. I want to be able to allow the user to create their own using custom fields.

Here's the object that represents a lower-third graphic right now.

```
{
_id: 'jdksl;alkdfghjd',
type: 'lowerthird',
style: 'cvhp' //this matches the graphic's style with a show for styling
fields: [
  {
    name: 'Joe Somebody',
    info: 'CVHP Digital Bureau'
  },
]
}
```

So far, I've been able to use the fields array as a way to generalize whatever information I want to display on the graphic when it's displayed on the screen but I'm not understanding how I'll be able to use this pattern when I start figuring out how to let users build custom graphics. I can define and display graphics all day long and, as long as I know what's in the fields everything's golden. If I know I need to display the name of the first field, I just grab `graphic.fields[0].name` and run with it. But how do I start to tackle user-generated objects whose fields I don't have any information about? Moreover, I don't even know if my data is shaped in a way that makes the most sense for this.

Does anyone know of any good references, tutorials, guides that handle this? Thanks in advance!

*edit*
The code I use for displaying the generated content is pretty basic but it's specific to the framework I'm using, Svelte. In my case, I'm displaying a list of the created graphics objects:

```
{#each $graphics as graphic}
  <article class="graphic-item">
    <header>
      <h3>{graphic.type}</h3>
      <img src={'/assets/images/' + graphic.style + '.png'} />
    </header>
    <section class="graphic-item-body">
      <ul class="graphic-item-field-list">
        {#each graphic.fields as field, index}
          <li>
            <p class="list-title">{Object.values(field)[0]}</p>
            {#if Object.values(field)[1]}
              <p class="list-subtitle">{Object.values(field)[1]}</p>
            {/if}
            {#if Object.values(field)[2]}
              <p class="list-subtitle">{Object.values(field)[2]}</p>
            {/if}
            {#if Object.values(field)[3]}
              <p class="list-subtitle">{Object.values(field)[3]}</p>
            {/if}
          </li>
        {/each}
      </ul>
    </section>
  </article>
{/each}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this question belongs here. usually, this is a good place to come when you have already found something, tried it and got stuck.

Comment: Great explanation of your problem but I'm not sure that it is really related to `svelte`.

Comment: Okay. I thought members of this community might have suggestions for patterns to this specific problem. I'll seek out an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Can you add the code you use for displaying to your question, please? Without that, it's really unclear what the problem is. But yes, in general you can only allow the user to define custom fields that your display code knows about.

Comment: you should first answer how you want to store the user-supplied fields or information. Otherwise, this question isn't very good and we can't answer it as any answer would first have to answer "How does a user supply values?" which only you can do.

Comment: @Bergi, I updated the question with the framework-specific code I'm using to display these items to the user.

Comment: Thanks. How would the custom user-generated fields look? Would they all have `name` and `info`, and you just don't know how many there are? Or is your worry that they would have completely arbitrary properties?

Comment: You will want to use a loop over `Object.values(field)` instead of those repeated `if` statements. Btw, you should not rely on the order of properties in an object. Instead of having the "first" item show up as the list-title, better access a specific property.

Comment: Right now the user facing fields are specific to the graphic being created. I was hoping to find a good way to compose the graphic object that's general enough so that users can start creating their own "non-standard" graphics on-the-fly. And thank you for suggesting `Object.values(field)`. I'll refactor to use that instead.